# How can I create and mount a shadow copy from a batch file on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vss

I would like to be able snapshot the system volume, mount that shadow copy, then run my own hand-rolled copy on it all from a batch file. How can I do this on Windows 7?

Comment: Is this for 1 desktop or a corporate environment? Would it equally apply to Server 2008?

Comment: @Andrew: You caught me. It's for a single desktop, but I figured the ServerFauly folks would be more likely to have an answer than the SuperUser folks because mucking with VSS isn't something I'd expect a user to do. IIRC, Win2008 has a binary that'll do this from the cmdline, so that's why I specified Win7.